# How to get the list of enumerated certificates in a windows security dialog

Tags: c#, winapi, windows-7, automation, ui-automation

I am trying to automate a test which involves authenticating to a website through a smartcard.

I am using c#, windows 7.

When I launch the url, a `windows security` window comes up asking me to select a certificate from the list of certificates available.

I am finding it impossible to come up with a way to iterate through the list of certificates listed in the security dialog box programatically. I just need to iterate through the list and keep reading the friendly name of the certificates listed till I find the one that matches my desired certificate.

Answer (score 3):

```
AutomationElementCollection windows =  AutomationElement.RootElement.FindAll(TreeScope.Descendants, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Window));
        foreach (AutomationElement window in windows)
        {
            if (window.Current.ClassName.Equals("#32770"))   //security dialog
            {
                AutomationElementCollection certs = window.FindAll(TreeScope.Descendants, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty,ControlType.ListItem));
                foreach (AutomationElement cert in certs)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(cert.Current.Name);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: This is a great solution, but I am having issues with this for Windows 10.  It seems the Windows Security dialog for certificates is different (IE11, not edge) compared to previous Windows 8 or 7.  I grabbed the full list of windows and output it and there is no window with a class name of #32770.  Anyone know how I can find this dialog for Windows 10?